# How does GRANT privileges function when recursive privileges?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I'm trying to understand how does granting privileges work on SQL.

According to what I understand, one user has privilege as long as said user has been granted privilege by someone or owns the database. And the second condition I though was true, is that a user may have a certain privilege only if someone the privilege chain connects to the owner/admin of the table.

Now, I'm using PostgreSQL to test how this works in an actual DBMS.

For example, let's say we have a table **t1** and the users **u1**, **u2**, **u3** and **u4**. Also let's assume **u1** is the owner.

- Now, **u1** grants `SELECT ON t1 TO u2 WITH GRANT OPTION`
- Then, **u1** grants `SELECT ON t1 TO u2 WITH GRANT OPTION`
- Then, **u2** grants `SELECT ON t1 TO u3 WITH GRANT OPTION`
- Then, **u3** grants `SELECT ON t1 TO u4 WITH GRANT OPTION`
- At last, **u4** grants `SELECT ON t1 TO u2 WITH GRANT OPTION`

This should leave a cycle of recursion of grants between **u2**, **u3** and **u4**. This means I can safely `REVOKE` the link between **u1** and **u2**, and the link between **u1** and **u3**. According to SQL the privileges from **u2**, **u3** and **u4** should be removed because they have no connection to the owner/admin of the table, but instead PostgreSQL allows this to happens and you can actually still issue `SELECT` on `t1` even after the privilege was revoked.

So the question is, is this the expected behaviour on PostgreSQL/any RDBMS, or am I understanding wrong how SQL privileges should work. If someone could clarify this a bit for me, I would be thankful.

I was using [these](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/aut07/slides/auth.pdf) slides to understand. The last slide is the case I'm talking about.

EDIT:

Updated the example to recreate how does the database ends up on the state shown on the picture below.

[image: Actual example and how the database remains.]

Comment: [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-NOTES) states: "*For example, if table t1 is owned by role g1, of which role u1 is a member, then u1 can grant privileges on t1 to u2, but those privileges will appear to have been granted directly by g1*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sure, but that happens when a certain role is member of another role. In this particular case each role has permits and if you grant them and check `\z t1` you will see that u2 granted r* to u3 and u3 granted r* to u2. PD: Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: What Postgres version? Tried to reproduce this on 11, and when trying to close the grant loop, I get `ERROR:  grant options cannot be granted back to your own grantor`. It succeeds without the `GRANT OPTION` on the final command, but the `REVOKE ... CASCADE` cleans everything up as expected. If it behaves differently on older versions, I guess that means they recognised it as a bug and fixed it.

Comment: I'm currently using version 10. The actual example I am using it leaves a cycle between 3 users. Something like **u1**, **u2** and **u3**.

It does give the exact same error as you do. I will review my example with the actual case. My bad :/